# Count points per raster attribute in R

Tags: raster, r

This may be a simple question but can't seem to find an answer. I've got a `raster` with 5 attributes, and a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`. I would like to count the number of points that fall within each attribute of the raster (i.e. how many points fall within attribute 1, how many within 2, etc...).

My raster looks like this:

```
 > ratify(r.class)
 class      : RasterLayer 
 dimensions : 168, 432, 72576  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
 resolution : 0.8333333, 0.8333333  (x, y)
 extent     : -180, 180, -56, 84  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
 source     : memory
 names      : layer 
 values     : 1, 5  (min, max)
 attributes :
 ID
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Use `raster::extract` to assign the raster values to your points and then `tapply` or `table` to get the class frequencies.